# Meta tags: discussion and proposals

Tags: discussion, tags

#### Add:

- [site-policies](/questions/tagged/site-policies), [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope), [voting](/questions/tagged/voting), [closing](/questions/tagged/closing), [main-tags](/questions/tagged/main-tags), [meta-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-tags)
- [case-study](/questions/tagged/case-study) — Interesting and controversial questions asked by users on the main site that cross or push the boundaries of the site scope.

#### Remove:

- [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks)

#### Combine:

- [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics), [acceptable-questions](/questions/tagged/acceptable-questions), [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) → [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope)
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging), [lumping-and-splitting](/questions/tagged/lumping-and-splitting) → [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)
- [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions), [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) → [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) → [closing](/questions/tagged/closing)
- [chat-sessions](/questions/tagged/chat-sessions) → [chat](/questions/tagged/chat)
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes), [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) → [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)
- [winterbash-2014](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) → [events](/questions/tagged/events)
- [fillers](/questions/tagged/fillers) → [main-tags](/questions/tagged/main-tags)

#### Split:

- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) → [main-tags](/questions/tagged/main-tags), [meta-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-tags)
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) → [voting](/questions/tagged/voting), [closing](/questions/tagged/closing)

Comment: `status*` tags are default on every system to denote whether a feature request or bug has been completed or in review, etc..

Comment: "Why are there used tags that don't have a "x #" next to them?" - These are per-child-meta automatically-existing tags.

Comment: [hyperlinks], [retagging], [asking-questions], [specific-question], [close-reasons], [down-votes], [up-votes], [tags], and [vote-to-close] are all [default meta tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233922/) and cannot be removed from the system.

Comment: @senshin I feel this question is kind of moot now that 1) as you said, most tags are default and can't be removed, and 2) as Logan said in chat, he (and I doubt most people) doesn't search by tags on meta (and they probably don't help SEO much either).

Comment: @GaoWeiwei That, too - on a large meta like Meta.SO or Meta.SE, a robust tagging system is helpful, but our meta is really quite small, and I don't know that there's much point in going around retagging stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is my opinion on some of the items in the question:

- <kbd>**Done**</kbd> <s>[hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks)</s> → [external-links](/questions/tagged/external-links) (since both questions on this tag are about external links)
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging), [lumping-and-splitting](/questions/tagged/lumping-and-splitting) → [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)
- [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) → [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)

  [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) specifically refers to the process (the flow) of asking question on SE, but it seems people might mistag it with [questions](/questions/tagged/questions). I don't know if this retagging should be done or not.

  Retain [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), which is used when the meta question is pertaining to a specific question on the main site.
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) → Close vote is a concept which deserves its own tag, so we should not split this tag.

  On meta.SO, there are [vote-to-close](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vote-to-close), [closed-questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed-questions), [close-reasons](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons) among a few other tags. I feel that it is not a good idea to copy this model, since it is quite confusing.
- [chat-sessions](/questions/tagged/chat-sessions) → Don't change this tag. It contains chat sessions about site policies.
- [winterbash-2014](/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) → Just leave this tag alone.
- <kbd>**Done**</kbd> <s>[fillers](/questions/tagged/fillers)</s> → I just killed this tag, since it doesn't look like a recurring meta topic.